# Running from the police

Tags: criminal-law

If an officer pulls a car over and I get out start running, the officer ends up hurting himself, can I be charged with a felony and how much jail time if any?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about a felony regarding the officers injury? You will be charged with evading arrest, which may result in a felony for that, independent of the officer injury... What Country/State are you in? What type of injury did the officer get?

Comment: Not a lawyer, but if an officer dies while chasing you, you’d probably get done for Manslaughter or Felony Murder, depending on whether Evading Arrest is a Felony or Misdemeanour. Not sure about if one just got injured, though.

Comment: Varies wildly by jurisdiction and other details might matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're in the US, because that's what I can answer.

1) "Pulls over *a* car" So... Are you in the car that got pulled? Because if you're not and you get out, run away from a scene you have no part in, and the officer injures himself at the scene you have nothing to do with and are leaving... I don't see how you could be charged, barring any duty to render aid statutes.

2) If the officer pulls *you* over and you flee, you can be charged with Evading Arrest, which may be a felony depending on the exact jurisdiction. If you do something which causes the injury to the officer, (like knocking over debris behind you) then you could be charged for the assault on the officer. If the officer trips over something which you did not plant/had no part in planting, then likely you're still getting stuck with the Evading Arrest charge.

3) The officer may simply use a Taser on you to avoid this situation, like in the YouTube clip that went viral about a year ago.

If you're looking to "get out of" a ticket, hiring a lawyer and going to court is your best bet.